# Pandas: Two equal columns and short second column according to the first

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to sort the second, the second column is equal to the first but is missing some values.

Data before:

```
     Cat1  Cat2
1    fish  dog
2    dog   ant
3    cat   fox
4    ant   NaN
5    fox   NaN
```

Data after:

```
     Cat1  Cat2
1    fish  NaN
2    dog   dog
3    cat   NaN
4    ant   ant
5    fox   fox
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left join by filter each column separately to one column `DataFrame`s:

```
df = df[['Cat1']].merge(df[['Cat2']], left_on='Cat1', right_on='Cat2', how='left')
print (df)
   Cat1 Cat2
0  fish  NaN
1   dog  dog
2   cat  NaN
3   ant  ant
4   fox  fox
```